# Force a roaming profile to be created

Tags: roaming-profile

SBS 2000 server; I've added `\\server\profiles\<username>` to each user's Active Directory's Profile tab, but 2 of 6 users are giving me grief: one finally was created for one of the two users last night (after two nights of logging off, including one `gupdate /sync /boot`).  And the other user just logged off now with `gupdate /force /boot` but no dice.

Besides using Copy To from My Computer > Properties > Advanced > Profiles, how else can I force the roaming profile to be created and/or what causes the delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client OS is "in charge" of uploading the user's roaming profile, ultimately. I've had cases with both Windows XP (occasionally) and Windows Vista (somewhat frequently) where changing a user's AD account profiles for their profile was blithely ignored by the client with very little diagnostic output.

Sometimes tweaking the "NextLogonCacheable" and "RefCount" values in the key for the affected user's SID under "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" can make a difference. Apparently [some nVidia drivers](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=79404) can cause these kinds of problems (!!!).

I've had cases where I've just given up, created the profile folder on the server w/ the appropriate permissions (which I typically do anyway-- I don't like allowing the clients to create profile folders), and just hand-copied everything up there while logged-on as another user.

Comment: Wow, NVidia?  Really?  Sigh.  I'll give some of those options a shot, but will likely just manually copy it up.